# Haskell Lists - Count fst of tuples and compare with length of list

Tags: list, haskell

I have the following list:

```
[(Libri,50.0),(Proxis,20.0),(Proxis,45.0),(Amazon,45.0)]
```

And I have a certain List called `articles`.
I want to transform the list above, with tuples so that if I have (length articles) times the first element of a tuple showing up in the list, get only that!

So, for example, if I have a list `articles=["HP","Haskell"]`, the list should show:

```
[(Proxis,20.0),(Proxis,45.0)]
```

Because `Proxis` shows up two times!

Edit:

Data Types:

```
data Magasin = Proxis | Amazon | Libri deriving (Eq, Show)
type Article = String
type Prix = Float
data Entree = E Magasin Article Prix deriving (Eq, Show)
type Stock = [Entree]
```

This is my  current code:

```
disponible::[Article]->Stock->[(Magasin,Float)]
disponible [] stk = []
disponible (art:reste) stk = (foldl(\acc (E m a p)->if a==art then (m,p):acc else acc) [] stk)++(disponible reste stk)
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

```
disponible::[Article]->Stock->[(Magasin,Float)]
disponible articles stock = map(\(m,ls)->(m,sum $ map (\(E _ _ p)->p) ls)) $ filter ((==length articles).length.snd) magasinsArticles
     where contientArticles = (filter (\(E _ a _)->a`elem`articles) stock)
           magasins = foldl (\acc e-> if e`elem`acc then acc else (e:acc)) [] $ map (\(E m _ _)->m) contientArticles
           magasinsArticles = map (\m->(m,filter(\(E m2 _ _)->m2==m) contientArticles)) magasins
```

Found the answer I was looking for.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you take the length of `articles` and emit every "article" that occurs that often in the given list?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Actually, the question is to find, given a list of articles, the Magasin (shop) that has all of them. My code works for one book in the list of articles:
`disponible ["HP7"] [(E Proxis "HP7" 20), (E Libri "HP7" 50), (E Amazon "Haskell" 45), (E Proxis "Haskell" 45)]` 
emits 
`[(Libri,50.0),(Proxis,20.0)]` . 
But if I give a List containing more than 1 article: 
`disponible ["HP7","Haskell"] [(E Proxis "HP7" 20), (E Libri "HP7" 50), (E Amazon "Haskell" 45), (E Proxis "Haskell" 45)]`
emits 
`[(Libri,50.0),(Proxis,20.0),(Proxis,45.0),(Amazon,45.0)]`.

Comment: So, it emits the shops that has either one or the other, not the shop that has both :/

Comment: what if there are multiple articles in the list that occur twice?

Comment: Maybe my approach is incorrect; I must return the shop(s) that has ALL the articles mentioned in the list of articles. My current code returns all the shop(s) that has either one of the articles. So if the shop A has Book1, shop A has Book2, shop C has Book1, shop D has Book2 and articles = ["Book1", "Book2"], my code returns shop A, shop A, shop C, shop D - it should returns shop A twice (because two books) but no shop C or shop D.

Comment: Found it:
`disponible::[Article]->Stock->[(Magasin,Float)]
disponible articles stock = map(\(m,ls)->(m,sum $ map (\(E _ _ p)->p) ls)) $ filter ((==length articles).length.snd) magasinsArticles
     where contientArticles = (filter (\(E _ a _)->a`elem`articles) stock)
           magasins = foldl (\acc e-> if e`elem`acc then acc else (e:acc)) [] $ map (\(E m _ _)->m) contientArticles
           magasinsArticles = map (\m->(m,filter(\(E m2 _ _)->m2==m) contientArticles)) magasins`

Comment: Please put your answer as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
disponible::[Article]->Stock->[(Magasin,Float)]
disponible articles stock = map(\(m,ls)->(m,sum $ map (\(E _ _ p)->p) ls)) $ filter ((==length articles).length.snd) magasinsArticles
     where contientArticles = (filter (\(E _ a _)->a`elem`articles) stock)
           magasins = foldl (\acc e-> if e`elem`acc then acc else (e:acc)) [] $ map (\(E m _ _)->m) contientArticles
           magasinsArticles = map (\m->(m,filter(\(E m2 _ _)->m2==m) contientArticles)) magasins
```